# Remove data from JQuery dialog box when I close it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JQuery dialog box for inserting new row in table. And everything works good. Few days ago when I inserted FlexiGrid for Table started a problem for me. When I insert new row dialog dissapear but when I open dialog for new insert data that is inserted before is still in dialog.

How to reset dialog fields after I finish with it's usage.

The code for dialog is this:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
        $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 250,
            width: 300,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Salva: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'agendaTipoAppuntamentoSaveJson.do',

                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: $("#newDialogForm").serialize(),
                      success: function(result) {
                          if (result.esito!='OK') {
                              alert(result.esito + ' ' + result.message);  
                          }
                          else {
                              addNewTipoAppuntamento(
                                            result.insertedTipoApp.idTipoAppuntamento , 
                                            result.insertedTipoApp.codice, 
                                            result.insertedTipoApp.descrizione, 
                                            result.insertedTipoApp.descrBreve, 
                                            result.insertedTipoApp.colore
                             );
                             $("#newTable").flexReload(); 
                             $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog( 'close' );
                          }
                       },
                       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                           alert(xhr.status);
                           alert(thrownError);
                       }  
                    });
                 },
                 Annula : function() {
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
              }
        });

        $( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog({ closeText: ''  });
 });
```

This is dialog form:

```
<div id="newDialog-form" title="Nuovo Tipo Appuntamento" class="inputForm"   >
    <form id="newDialogForm" action="agendaTipoAppuntamentoSaveJson.do"  >
    <input type="hidden" name="azione" id="idAzione" value="update"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="idTipoAppuntamento" id="idTipoAppuntamentoIns" value="-1"  />
    <fieldset>
       <table>
            <tr >
            <td>
            <label for="codiceIns">Codice </label>
            </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="codice" id="codiceIns" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
            </td></tr><tr>
            <td>
            <label for="descrizioneIns">Descrizione </label>
            </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="descrizione" id="descrizioneIns" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"   />
            </td></tr><tr>
            <td>
            <label for="descrBreveIns">descrBreve </label>
            </td><td>
            <input type="text" name="descrBreve" id="descrBreveIns" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"  />
            </td></tr><tr>
            <td>
            <label for="coloreIns">colore </label>
            </td><td>
            <input type="text"  name="colore" id="coloreIns" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"  />
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `How to reset dialog fields after I finish with it's usage` can you explain in more detail

Comment: I just want to clear data from form fields when I press Save od Cancel in form, so when i open it again I have clear form and not form with previous data

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check [Dialog Close](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close) event. You will need to store the state of dialogue, state will include (title, text etc), if you are modifying it.

**Update**

After reading the comment, what I got, giving answer according to it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Before you open the dailog form, store the html to local variable and then before closing it set the html back to the dialogue.

```
var originalContent;
$("#newDialog-form").dialog({
   //Your Code, append following code
   open : function(event, ui) { 
      originalContent = $("#newDialog-form").html();
   },
   close : function(event, ui) {
      $("#newDialog-form").html(originalContent);
   }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried that approach, and it works fine in terms of restoring the html structure. But the **events** attached to any controls on the dialog **seem to be lost** because they are not saved within the structure. I'll try to add an extra ApplyDialogEvents() function to the open event of the dialog, to see if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Would it work if you add this line to the function of Save or Cancel?

```
 $( "#newDialog-form" ).html("");
```

or more straight method (thx @mplungjan):

```
 $( "#newDialog-form" ).empty();
```

It makes that all the content inside the dialog disappear, it's the best way so that last data does not appear.

Comment: @mplungjan: or empty() (I add it to my answer. Thx), that's another straight solution, the thing is that whatever code it is thought, it can be solved without looking for dialog methods.

Comment: it deletes everything from dialog. No more rows for inserting when I open it 2nd time. Same with html() and with empty()

Comment: @Akosha: you should provide the html that is inside the Dialog, and you could reset every field inside. The same that I do with the whole dialog, but input by input.

Comment: @netadictos: I know I am rude but can you provide me some code example how to do it. I am litlle confused :S

Comment: @Akosha. No problem, but I don't know which is the html inside the Dialog, could you provide it? If it is automated, pls use firebug

Comment: @mplungjan - broken link (404 error). Could you share a new link please?

Comment: Sorry - I do not have a new link

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `close` event of jQuery dialogs.

More information on [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close).

e.g.

```
$( "#newDialog-form" ).dialog({
    ...
    close : function() {
        //functionality to clear data here
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try to avoid writing my own function for clearing data in dialog... Maybe someone have solution for that :S

Answer (score 1):

you can clean all html content in DIV by setting the html property to nothing.

```
$("#ElementId").html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the HTML in dialog every time you open it and then do this:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
$(this).remove();
```

..after you're done inserting the new record, usually after

```
$('#yourForm').submit();
```

Cheers!