# Remove unsaved text from jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a jQuery dialog form that allows a user to save notes. Here's the scenarios:

1. A user opens the dialog for the first time and adds a note (when they reopen the dialog the new note shows up)
2. The user opens the dialog, types something then clicks cancel (when they reopen the dialog the note shows up as saved in step 1 which is good)
3. The user opens the dialog and updates the note (when they reopen the dialog the note has changed as desired)
4. The user opens the dialog and clicks cancel (now when they reopen the dialog the note reverts back the saved value from step 1)

So, the problem arises when a user updates a note, then reopens the dialog and hits cancel. The form reverts back to the very first save. Here's the script:

```
  jQuery(function() { 
  var originalContent;
    jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      height: 480,
      width: 460,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
          jQuery( ".edit_user_property" ).submit();
          jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog('close');
        },        
        "Cancel": function(event, ui) {
          jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).html(originalContent).dialog('close');
        },
      },
      open: function(event, ui) {
        originalContent = jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).html();
      },
    }),
    jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function() {
      originalContent = jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).html();
      jQuery( ".edit_user_property" ).submit();
    })
  });
```

I'm trying to store the current state as outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969084/2074243 then pass it when the user cancels. I've tried to update my variable on change and submit, but neither worked. It seems like the variable is one step behind. My dialog is opened by a link_to_function:

```
    <%=link_to_function("Notes", 'jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" )' %>
```

if that matters. Also, I running Rails 2.3.17, thus the use of jQuery vs. $. Also, here's the form if it helps:

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Notes";"> 
      <form action="/properties/add_notes" class="edit_user_property" id="edit_user_property_108458" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/properties/200465/add_notes', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="6/D6syvFo5nuLxla9dzcIadK5NbYxpPGKqilOwT+7Xw=" /></div>
        <textarea id="user_property_notes" name="user_property[notes]" placeholder="Add notes" rows="20">Great property right</textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: a few questions - Cancel should be 'Cancel' and you're missing a # on your selector within the cancel function. Also, it doesn't look like you are updating the originalContent variable on the `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` click function.

Comment: I've updated the script. Still having the same issues. Any other suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value for originalContent is being overwritten by the value from the original dom. If you set a break point where you expect it to be changed you'll see it hasn't.

But, you can save the values in the form with form.serializeArray and store that when the user successfully saves something `data = tmp...`. Then restore it if they "cancel", by looping through the values and resetting the form fields to their previously saved values `data.forEach...`. Depending on what kind of form elements you use and if some are widgets you might have to reinitialize those elements.

Here is a [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/GcDut)

If you are using the same html, remove your onsubmit function from it (see the codepen)

otherwise, given your HTML...

```
$(function(){

    var
        form = $( ".edit_user_property" ),
        data = form.serializeArray(),
        close = function(){
            form.dialog("close");
        },
        cancel = function(){
            data.forEach(function(v){
                 form.find('[name="'+v.name+'"]').val(v.value)
            });
            close();
        },
        save = function(){
            var tmp = form.serializeArray();
            console.log("save",tmp)
            $.ajax('/properties/200465/add_notes', {
                asynchronous:true, 
                evalScripts:true, 
                parameters:form.serialize()
            })
                .done(function(response){
                    alert("PASS");
                    data = tmp;
                    close();
                })
                .fail(function(response){
                    alert("FAIL");
                    close();
                });
        };
    form
        .dialog({
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save":save,
                "Cancel":cancel
            },
            close:close
        })
        .on("submit",function(){return false;})
    $("a").click(function(){
        form.dialog("open");
    });
})
```

Comment: When I click the save button a GET request is sent, so the the dialog alert("fail") pops up. I removed the onsubmit from the html (changed the remote_form_for to form_for) with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible to post it in a new fiddle so I can take a look? why did the server fail? also what is "remote_form_for" i don't see a prior mention anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using val() instead of html() for the variable, grabbing only the textarea, storing the content on save/close (I wanted close to save) only and resetting on cancel. Here's the update function:

```
    jQuery(function() { 
      var originalContent;
      jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 480,
        width: 460,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          "Save": function() {
            originalContent = jQuery( "#dialog-form textarea" ).val();
            jQuery( ".edit_user_property" ).submit();
            jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog('close');
          },        
          "Cancel": function(event, ui) {
            jQuery( "#dialog-form textarea" ).val(originalContent);
            jQuery( "#dialog-form" ).dialog('close');
          },
        },
      }),
      jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function() {
        originalContent = jQuery( "#dialog-form textarea" ).val();
        jQuery( ".edit_user_property" ).submit();
      })
    });
```